# "alias: =: not found", and alias not defined, with "alias ll = 'ls -l'" in .bashrc

Tags: bash, alias

I'm on Mac OSX and trying to put some basic aliases in .bashrc (e.g. `alias ll = 'ls -l'`). I sourced .bashrc in .bash_profile, and on startup it recognizes a function that I have in .bashrc. However, I get the following error messages every time I add an alias and then try to start it up:

```
-bash: alias: ll: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: ls -l: not found
```

The ll alias does not work, but the command declared by the following function does:

```
#!/bin/bash
# prints the input
function print_my_input() {
  echo 'Your input: ' $1
}
```

Is there an additional step I need to do to create normal aliases?

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=` in the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -la'

alias cd..='cd ..'
alias ..='cd ..'
```

Bash does not allow a space before and after an `=` sign when assigning variables as well as aliases.

On a sidenote, there are two ways to declare a function:

Using the keyword `function` to indicate a function declaration

```
function myfunction { # function is a keyword
    echo hello
}
```

or by simply putting braces after the function name and omitting the `function` keyword

```
myfunction() { # () indicate a function definition
    echo hello
}
```

Using both is not an error but redundant. Furthermore, *Charles Duffy* points out in the comments:

> ...not just redundant, but also needlessly nonportable. myfunction() {
>   is guaranteed to work on all POSIX shells; function myfunction { works
>   on old ksh (and is supported in bash for compatibility with same);
>   combining the two doesn't work on baseline-POSIX or on old ksh.

Comment: ...not just redundant, but also needlessly nonportable. `myfunction() {` is guaranteed to work on all POSIX shells; `function myfunction {` works on old ksh (and is supported in bash for compatibility with same); combining the two doesn't work on baseline-POSIX *or* on old ksh.