# How do you create an alias for ssh commands in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to create an alias for the ssh command in my .bashrc file on my user. Here is what my .bashrc looks like:

```sh
alias ll = 'ls -al'
alias tron = 'ssh sshtron.zachlatta.com'
```

This didn't turn out to work. Here is what always logs when I open Git Bash:

```
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ls -al: not found
bash: alias: tron: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: ssh sshtron.zachlatta.com: not found
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900891/alias-not-found-and-alias-not-defined-with-alias-ll-ls-l-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces.  `alias tron='ssh sshtron.zachlatta.com'`

Comment: Ahah get ready, 90% of the time it will be like this. 
they take the solution they disappear. (PS: i got you, +1 for you)